# how to join ifconfig output to a line per interface

Tags: sed, line, ifconfig

how do i convert the following output with sed?
from:

```
lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
igb0: flags=9040843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DEPRECATED,IPv4,NOFAILOVER> mtu 1500 index 2
    inet 10.1.1.1 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.1.1.255
    groupname mnic_data
```

to:

```
lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1 inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
igb0: flags=9040843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DEPRECATED,IPv4,NOFAILOVER> mtu 1500 index 2 inet 10.1.1.1 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.1.1.255 groupname mnic_data
```

I have tried

```
sed -n '/^[a-z]/{x;1!s/\n/ /g;1!p;};H'
```

but no luck! appreciate your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifconfig |
awk '
    FNR>1 && /^[^[:space:]]/ {print ""}
    {printf "%s", $0}
    END {print ""}
'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$ sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n / /;ta' -e 'P;D' inputfile
lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
igb0: flags=9040843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DEPRECATED,IPv4,NOFAILOVER> mtu 1500 index 2    inet 10.1.1.1 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.1.1.255    groupname mnic_data
```

EDIT: To get rid of the extra spaces in the output above, you can use:

```
$ sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n\s\+/ /;ta' -e 'P;D' inputfile
lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1 inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
igb0: flags=9040843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DEPRECATED,IPv4,NOFAILOVER> mtu 1500 index 2 inet 10.1.1.1 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.1.1.255 groupname mnic_data
```

Answer (score 0):

does this help (awk)?

```
awk '/:/&&f{print ""}{printf "%s", $0;f=1}'
```

test

```
kent$  echo "lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
igb0: flags=9040843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DEPRECATED,IPv4,NOFAILOVER> mtu 1500 index 2
    inet 10.1.1.1 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.1.1.255
    groupname mnic_data"|awk '/:/&&f{print ""}{printf "%s", $0;f=1}'
lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
igb0: flags=9040843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DEPRECATED,IPv4,NOFAILOVER> mtu 1500 index 2    inet 10.1.1.1 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.1.1.255    groupname mnic_data
```

Comment: If `ifconfig` emits ipv6 addresses or mac addresses, they will have colons.